# Possible real world counterpart to Jane Eldon / Sean Gogerty?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek Voyager [Season 6 Episode 11](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fair_Haven_(episode)) episode *Fair Haven* Captain Janeway was introduced to an early 19th century Irish poet [Jane Eldon's](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Eldon) work [Hills Most Green, Hearts Unseen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hills_Most_Green,_Hearts_Unseen) by a holographic character [Michael Sullivan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Sullivan).  The rhyming scheme is similar to a contemporary Irish poet [Sean Gogerty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sean_Gogerty).

From the 2021 *Tor.com* web article [Star Trek:Voyager Rewatch: “Fair Haven”](https://www.tor.com/2021/05/24/star-trek-voyager-rewatch-fair-haven/)

> Jane Eldon and Sean Gogerty are both fictional poets. It’s not clear why Burger didn’t have Janeway and Sullivan reading any actual Irish poets, of which there are more than a few.

Has anyone made a good theory or do we know if the Star Trek Voyager *Fair Haven* episode writer [Robin Burger](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Robin_Burger)
has said anything about who Jane Eldon / Sean Gogerty's counterpart is in real Irish history?